# Synchronize mySQL table in PHP/PDO with extern loaded data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**My case:** a *MySQL* table stores all the followers from my twitter account.
I load these id's with the *twitter* API and `INSERT` them in the table with `status = 1`.

I am looking for a solution to update the table, so the unfollowers are set on `status = 0`.
The new followers will be added because the don't exists.

**My thoughts:** Set all statusses on 0, load data with the API, if id still exist set status back on 1, if id don't exist update table. So, the unfollowers are left as `status = 0`.

Is this the best way to do it or has *MySQL* a code for it?

Thanks.

Comment: First question is, as always, **what have you tried?** Your explanation here is really muddled and you haven't given even a tiny example of the sort of thing you're trying to do. A simple, stripped down table schema would be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Why should I try coding something what's in developers thinking stadium. The question is ment for help in a direction. Thanks for the downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a new column with the timestamp of the last status update.
When you update for your followers the timestamp should be updated too if they still follow you.
Then select all the followers in the database that don't have the timestamp updated to the last followers check and set their status to 0.